# NodeJS: Google Sign-In for server-side apps

Tags: node.js, google-api

Following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) I succeed to perform Google Sign-In for server-side apps and have access to user's GoogleCalendar using Python on server side. I fail to do that with NodeJS.

Just in a nutshell - with Python I used the `auth_code` I've sent from the browser and got the credentials just like that:

```
from oauth2client import client

credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'profile', 'email'],
    auth_code)
```

Then I could store in DB the value of:

```
gc_credentials_json = credentials.to_json()
```

And generate credentials (yes it uses the refresh_token alone when it's needed):

```
client.Credentials.new_from_json(gc_credentials_json)
```

So I want to do the same using NodeJS:

1. easily generate credentials using just: `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE`, `scopes` and `auth_code` (just like I did with Python)
2. receive credentials using previous credentials value without analysing if the access token is expired - I prefer a ready (well tested by the community) solution

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, you have find solution?

Comment: Yes, I've just posted a short explanation of my solution as an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented it using `google-auth-library` package.

Here is the function to retrieve the gcClient:

```
const performAuth = async () => {
    const tokens = await parseTokenFromDB();
    const auth = new OAuth2Client(
        downloadedCredentialsJson.web.client_id,
        downloadedCredentialsJson.web.client_secret
    );
    auth.on('tokens', async (newTokens) => {
        updateDBWithNewTokens(newTokens);
    });
    await auth.setCredentials(tokens);
    const gcClient = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
    return gcClient;
};
```

Here is the template for `parseTokenFromCurrentDB` function just to give the idea of its output:

```
const parseTokenFromCurrentDB = async () => {
    // Put here your code to retrieve from DB the values below 
    return {
        access_token,
        token_type,
        refresh_token,
        expiry_date,
    };
};
```

So using this implementation one can get `gcClient`:

```
const gcClient = await gc.getGcClient(org);
```

and use its methods, e.g.:

```
const gcInfo = await gc.getInfo(gcClient);
const events = await gc.getEvents(gcClient, calcPeriodInGcFormat());
```